# Moving SVN Trunk head backward

Tags: svn, merge, trunk

The problem we encountered with our trunk is at one point someone was moving files and deleted a top level directory, committed that change then restored the directory and committed that change.

From the outside we thought that was fine... until other branches synced from trunk.
Now this meant that when syncing the branch SVN would delete that top level directory and then just re-add the trunks state of that dir... causing all changes in that dir to be lost on the branch (ouch).

Hence the need for a way to rewind the SVN head.

Our only thought was to make a branch from the previous commit and try to make that trunk but that seems like it may lead to some issues (like tree conflicts).

Comment: Have you considered switching to git?

Comment: How did you restore the directory? If you did it by reverting your deletion using SVN, then I'd expect it not to cause the problems you encountered. Did you just create a new folder with the same name instead of restoring with SVN?

Answer (score 0):

Try a reverse merge into trunk:

```
svn merge -r HEAD:prev .
```

Execute this in a current trunk working copy, the commit. `prev` should be the version before the directories were first deleted.

With this you will of course lose all changes to the trunk between now and `prev`, eg but at least your branches should be OK.

Comment: Thanks Michael, that would work fine to restore the trunk to look as it should. But the checkin that deleted the top level directory still causes all syncs to trunk to delete the top level directory and replace it with the original trunk copy (blowing away all changes in that directory).